# Getting Woocommerce product price with Timber

Tags: woocommerce, timber

How do I get the Woocommerce product price I would get using `<?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>` in a non Timber Wordpress template?

I tried `{{ product.price }}` but it triggers an error which says:

```
price was called incorrectly. Product properties should not be accessed directly.
```

I know that I can get it through the Woocommerce template using `{% do action('woocommerce_single_product_summary') %}`, but:

- I want the raw unformatted text, not the content of the Woocommerce template.
- the Woocommerce action also gets a bunch of other stuff I don't need.

So, how do I access it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a custom function to Timber that returns the raw price value. This goes in the `functions.php` file:

```
public function add_to_twig( $twig ) {
  $function = new Twig_Function('myprice', function () {
    global $product;
    $myprice = $product->get_price();
    return $myprice;
  });
  $twig->addFunction($function);
 
  return $twig;
}
```

it can be used in any Twig template with `{{ myprice() }}`